# What style guide does the Queen use?

Tags: style-manuals

Is there a known style guide or documented set of stylistic rules for the English language that Queen Elizabeth II and/or her office uses in emitted correspondence?  Is there any way to know how QE2 would write something without digging through old correspondence for similar uses?

Comment: Most things that are used and honoured collectively in Britain are said to be the Queen's. We have HM Armed Forces, HM Government, even HM Loyal Opposition (in Parliament). The calm on the streets is said to be 'The Queen's Peace'. If you break that peace you can be sent to HM Prison, and before the days of integral sanitation, you were issued with a chamber pot bearing the letters HM PRISON SERVICE. So not surprisingly, the standard elegant form of the language, used in educated circles I choose to name the 'Queen's English'. And that is what the Queen speaks.

Comment: @WS2: OK, but just how does the Queen speak & write?

Comment: I don't think she had a speaking part [in the Olympics ceremony](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AS-dCdYZbo), but you can listen to [her 2012 Christmas speech here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FYc9bNLS8U). (Sigh. What a dame! :)

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted—it’s quite an interesting question. Would official letters from the Queen, for example, use the Oxford comma? Spell _-ize_ or _-ise_? Use en or em dashes (close-set or spaced off)? Surprising as it may seem, I have never received a missive from the Queen, so I cannot answer these questions from firsthand knowledge.

Comment: At one time, the way the monarch spoke greatly influenced the language - howsoever she wants is probably the correct answer.

Comment: [The queen's style guide](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2010/11/21/snl-kate-middleton-queen_n_786543.html)

Comment: This is a toughy, considering that it’s been shown that [not even ER herself uses the Queen’s English anymore](http://phonetik.uni-muenchen.de/~jmh/research/papers/harrington00.nature.pdf).

Comment: Related question: Was the King's English what the Fowler brothers said it was, or what the King said it was? We may have stumbled upon the CoE correlative of papal infallibility.

Comment: The Queen ***is*** the style guide. Voting to close as a no-brainer (just kidding).

Comment: Are you asking if Queen Elizabeth's official correspondence is proofread by anyone before being sent? Does she actually write any official documents herself? I doubt it. I think a department in the civil service, or a qualified civil servant might be involved somewhere here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet She certainly wouldn't spell things -ize as in realize, or -or as in honor or neighbor. She knows far better than that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Bearing in mind that she is 87 years old and has been on the throne for 62 years, I too would be a little bit surprised if she does not have help with her voluminous correspondence. As she pointed out at a dinner party at Buck House, attended by the then-current and two former American Presidents 'my job is not something you do simply for two four-year terms'.

Comment: @WS2, obviously not _honor_, that's confined to AmE; but _-ize_ is almost as common in BrE as _-ise_, and several style guides (most prominently Oxford’s) require it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It might be fashionable among some modern academics, but anyone who was taught English properly, like the Queen was, in the first half of the twentieth century wouldn't touch it with a barge pole.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet By the way am I meant to be impressed by your citing Oxford? Cambridge is where it all happens.

Comment: @tchrist A brief scan of that article reveals it all to be about pronunciation. There is nothing sensational about the fact that the Queen does not use the usual middle-class received pronunciation (RP). She uses an accent often known as 'Marked RP', which is used by a tiny minority, mostly those of gentry connection. In MRP, one pronounces, for example 'off' as though it were spelled 'awfe' and 'cloth' as 'clawthe'. Some, who have tried to convert to MRP have spectacularly come to grief.

Comment: @WS2, impressed? Er, no, why should you be _impressed_ by a mere mentioning? Oxford just happens to be the most prominent (though not the only) style guide in the UK that advocates _-ize_ rather than _-ise_. Cambridge, where it all apparently happens, is as far as I know quite indifferent in the matter. And if by “modern academics” you mean the likes of _Hart’s Rules_ (1904) and Fowler’s _Dictionary of Modern English Usage_, then sure, consider it limited to “modern academics”. They’re modern academics that were quite influential in British schools even before the Queen was born, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What exactly is a style guide? Is it one of those things that tells you when to sign off 'yours sincerely' or 'yours faithfully'. And how have I managed to survive all these years without ever having used one?

Comment: @WS2 Since you [asked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Style_guides_for_American_English). [The Elements of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) and [AP Stylebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AP_Stylebook) are the two I'm most familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Queen Elizabeth II's government — The Prime Minister and the cabinet  — write her
official speeches. As explained here: [Queen's speech](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/queens-speech-2012-explained)

Nor is she the author of her official correspondence, according to the official British Monarchy website. ([Source](http://www.royal.gov.uk/TheRoyalHousehold/RoyalHouseholddepartments/ThePrivateSecretarysOffice/ThePrivateSecretarysOffice.aspx))

> The office of the Private Secretary, supports the Queen in her job as Head of State.  The current Private Secretary to The Queen is The Rt. Hon. Sir Christopher Geidt KCVO OBE who was appointed to his role in September 2007.
>
> **The Private Secretary is the channel of communication between the Head
>   of State and the Government**, not only in the United Kingdom but also
>   in the 15 other realms of which The Queen is Sovereign.
>
> [...]
>
> Other responsibilities include organising The Queen’s official
>   programme at home and overseas; liaising with the Households of other
>   members of the Royal Family; and **dealing with The Queen’s official
>   correspondence and correspondence with members of the public.**
>
> The Private Secretary prepares The Queen’s speeches and messages, and
>   his/her office arranges photographs and official presents, portraits
>   and messages of congratulation.

An exception to the rule is the Queen's Christmas speech which the [BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/4558862.stm) claims:

> The Queen writes her own Christmas speeches and it is one of the rare
>   occasions when she does not seek government advice and is able to
>   voice her own views.

The Guardian confirms that the [2012 Christmas speech](http://www.theguardian.com/uk/2012/dec/24/queen-3d-christmas-speech-glasses) was by her own hand.

> This year, her message, which she writes herself, will highlight the
>   "splendid summer of sport", and pay tribute to the nation's Olympic
>   and Paralympic athletes, who gave spectators the chance to revel in
>   the "excitement and drama".

Therefore, in order to know which style guide (if any) is employed, one would need to ask David Cameron, all the ministers of the British cabinet and finally, the Queen's private secretary Sir [Christopher Geidt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Geidt) themselves.

If it is of any help, the 47-year-old Prime Minister, David Cameron, attended Eton College before studying  Philosophy, Politics, and Economics at Oxford university, so presumably he is well-versed in the Queen's English.

Comment: Is *she is neither the author* grammatical in British English?

Comment: Yes, it is (I'm pretty certain, but why not ask the question on ELU?!) perhaps it should be recast.

Comment: @virmaior my edit should make more sense now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But when Cameron appeared on the David Letterman chat-show in America, oddly his Latin seemed to desert him. I should think the Classics master at Eton was having fits when DC couldn't translate 'Magna Carta' into English.

Comment: @WS2  Lucky for the Queen that her speeches are in English, although I seem to recall one famous *annus horribilis* discourse.